# Python: intersect of Iterables, which index-values are equal

Tags: python, function, methods, generator, yield

I need a function that expects any number of iterables. For this, you can assume that these iterables output their elements in the same order.

i want a function, which returns a list of the element, which are in the same place (same index) of the input iterables,
FOR EXAMPLE. for [1,2,3] and [1, "x", 3], 1 and 3 would be returned.
EXAMPLE: intersect((1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3)) would be return [1,2,3]

i tried it, but i think its totally wrong :C

```
def intersect(*args):
"""Docstring"""
ausgabe = []
anzahlderlisten = len(args)
count = 1
if(anzahlderlisten == 1):
    return args[0]
if(anzahlderlisten == 0):
    return []

längsteliste = args[0]
while count < anzahlderlisten:
    for i in längsteliste:
        if not i in args[count] and längsteliste.index(i) == args[count].index(i):
            print("db")
            if not(i in ausgabe):
                print("db")
                ausgabe.append(i)
        count = count + 1
    return ausgabe
```

Comment: I don't know what's the question here, and there's no attempt, nor desired output, nor current output.

Comment: Now you added some code – which is good– but you think it's no good. What in particular makes you think that?

Comment: because it dont work... its to complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be the following:

```
def all_same(items):       
    return all(item == items[0] for item in items[1:])

def get_agreeing(*iterables):
    assert len(iterables) >= 2
    return (row[0] for row in zip(*iterables) if all_same(row))


print(tuple(get_agreeing(range(3), range(1, 4), range(3))))
print(tuple(get_agreeing(range(3), (0, 4, 2), (1, 0, 2))))
```

`get_agreeing` uses variadic arguments, which means taking any number of arguments, putting them in an iterable, and passing that to the function. Thats done by the * syntax.

We then use the star again to pass those arguments to the zip function in the same manner they were passed to `get_agreeing`
So if you think of the iterables as column vectors you can think of all first elements as a row. For this row, you just need to check whether all elements are identical, and if they are, the first element from it will be returned by the resulting generator.

If you want to know more about variadic arguments or generators, see:

- https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/